# Unable to shortcut-abort with Italian keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a very simple problem : I am unable to Abort using "Alt+." when my keyboard is set in Italian. I press the combination, but it does not abort, I receive a Windows sound, like the one when you press something that is un-pressable.

However, if I switch to another keyboard (let's say Greek, for example), then executing the "Alt+." shortcut does indeed abort the computation. For reference here is the italian faulty dot : "." and the Greek one that works : "." although I'm pretty sure they are the same.

Edit : I tried that on several computers and it is reproducible. For some reason there is something happening with the Italian keyboard.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: what if you use the other Alt key on your keyboard?

Comment: Haha tried that, unfortunately doesn't work either. But I'm curious if you can reproduce this behavior on another computer ? I'll try it later today.